# create distance matrix from string column in dataframe

Tags: r

I try to use this code without success:

```
library(fuzzywuzzyR)
library(proxy)

set.seed(42)
rm(list = ls())
options(scipen = 999)

init = FuzzMatcher$new()

data <- data.frame(string = c("aaaaa baaaaa", "baaaaa xxxhhx ", "caaaaa hhhr ejhhehe"))
data$string <- as.character(data$string)

f <- function(string_1, string_2) {
    init$Token_set_ratio(string1 = string_1, string2 = string_2, force_ascii = TRUE, full_process = TRUE)
}

proxy::dist(data$string, method = f)
```

The aim is to generate distances between every row using the proxy::dist and fuzzywuzzyR packages.

**Error:**

> Error: both parameters 'string1' and 'string2' should be of type
>   character string
>        In addition: Warning message:
>               In do.call(".External", c(list(CFUN, x, y, pairwise, if (!is.function(method)) get(method) else method),  :
>                NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Where does it fail?

Comment: Why the close vote?!!! This is a perfectly reproducible question?! Honestly, SO these days is a pain ....

Comment: step 1: Make sure your `string` is set as character (not factor)

Comment: mmh - what does as.character do? did you try to run this?

Comment: `as.character` does exactly that, but the error says that they are not character. No I did not run it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on my machine and installed the fuzzywuzzyr package by install.packages. This installed the package fine but when I run `init$Token_set_ratio(string1 = s1, string2 = s2, force_ascii = TRUE, full_process = TRUE)`
 this gives me an error of `attempt to apply non-function` which in turn returns `NAs introduced by coercion` in the later call to `proxy::dist`. I believe the problem may be similar to `https://github.com/mlampros/fuzzywuzzyR/issues/4` and I can't even run the basic examples in the vignette. I believe the package is broken or not maintained, as I can't even run the utils section in the github repo without getting the same non function error. Sorry that this couldn't solve your problem, but maybe it'll help.

Comment: for your information the 'attempt to apply non-function' error means that you either don't have a correct Python configuration or one of the required Python packages is not installed in your Operating System. The commands 'reticulate::py_discover_config()' and 'reticulate::py_module_available('fuzzywuzzy')' might give you some hints in the correct direction.